# Endless-Loop of Numbers

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, input

i'm new in Python and this time i'm working on a "Lotto, 6 out of 45" Gen. This is german gambling. So the problem is:

```
import random
print("Willkommen im 6 aus 45 - Lotto Generator")


def Gen():
    for i in range(0,7):
        print(random.randint(0,45))
Gen()

v = input("Willst du einen neuen Versuch? Ja/Nein: ")

while True:
    if v == "Ja":
        Gen()
    elif v == "Nein":
        exit()
```

The Problem is: If you type in "Ja" at the End, there is an endless loop of numbers. I would be very glad if someone can help me.

I'm from Austria. I'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: reorder statements so the program would ask for input and check answer after every generation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you ask the question once, and then you loop forever. Instead, ask the question every time you loop:

```
while True:
    v = input("Willst du einen neuen Versuch? Ja/Nein: ")
    if v == "Ja":
        Gen()
    elif v == "Nein":
        exit()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry for this simple question :D

Answer (score 0):

Exit() or break in order to stop infinite loop